# I'm attempting to make an app that displays current location but the app won't display the map

Tags: android, dictionary, render

I'm new to coding and especially android development.I've made a simple calculator app for a start and it worked,my app doesn't display the map at all.I've been working on this for two days now but still can't figure out the problem.Please do tell me where I'm standing and where the problem is.
Please refer to the screenshot.
**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="inovationlabs.location" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

   </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
     <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"    />
</manifest>
```

**AND I get Rendering problems with the activity_maps.xml file,please tell me why?
activity_maps:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Goy.png
[SCREENSHOT]
This is what my app displays.

Comment: Have you created an API Key and added it to your AndroidManifest with additional permissions like this? 

 

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY" />

 <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapv2ex.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapv2ex.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

Comment: post your manifest.xml code

Comment: The screenshot says  your code must be ok otherwise the app would have crashed. The problem might be the key. I guess the key is not ok or might be the map is taking time to load.

Comment: Pretty sure the map is not taking time,because I've waited for so much time.The key is the right one.I've had the same doubt and cross checked it.

Comment: UPDATE: I'll post my manifest and maps_activity code

Answer (score 0):

You shold follow this guide:

[Getting Started with Google Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: I was already following that guide and still have difficulties.

Comment: You should check de api Key, you need one key for signed apk created with SHA1 from your custom keystore, and other one for debug testing created with de sha1 from your debug.keystore . LogCat print error messages from Google Maps check this for more information.  Clean project, delete application on device and debug again

Comment: I installed the debug apk.Still didn't work.And I always have a rendering error for my activity_maps.xml .Please take a look.

Comment: Please find in logcat the error message launched by google maps api and paste here. The message should says whats going on

Comment: I couldn't see <uses-permission> tags about maps in your manifest.

If you get an inflate exception, try wrapping your fragment  inside a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. That's how I always used map fragments, maybe that's it.

Comment: The fragment declaration in xml, should be this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Comment: If you want some help, paste Activity and Fragment code.